# Why is the function for deleting the last node of the linked list not working?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

The function **deleteLast()** is not working.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
struct node *head=NULL, *newNode, *temp;

void insertFirst(int data)
{
    newNode= new node;
    newNode->data=data;
    newNode->next=head;
    head=newNode;
}

void deleteFirst()
{
    newNode=head;
    head=head->next;
    free(newNode);
}

void deleteLast()
{
    newNode=head;
    while(newNode->next!=NULL)
    {
        newNode=newNode->next;
        temp=newNode->next;
    }
    newNode->next=NULL;
    free(temp);

}

void print()
{
    newNode=head;
    while(newNode!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",newNode->data);
        newNode=newNode->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    insertFirst(10);
    insertFirst(20);
    insertFirst(30);
    deleteLast();
    insertFirst(40);
    print();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is: 40 30 20 10.

If the deleteLast() function worked, the output would be: 40,30,20.

The function is supposed to remove the last node of the linked list.
So, where is the mistake in the function?

**Update**: Now it works after I edited the function this way:

```
void deleteLast()
{
    newNode=head;
    while(newNode->next->next!=NULL)
    {
        newNode=newNode->next;
        temp=newNode->next;
    }
    newNode->next=NULL;
    free(temp);

}
```

Comment: If your code can't be compiled with a C compiler, it should not be tagged with the C tag.

Comment: Why is `temp` a global variable? You shouldn't mix `new` with `free`, use `delete`

Comment: You can't combine `new` and `free`; it has undefined behaviour. `new` goes with `delete`, and `malloc` with `free`. (And don't use `malloc` and `free` in C++.)

Comment: When the loop finishes, `newNode->next` is `NULL`. `newNode->next=NULL` is nonsense.

Comment: `free(temp);` -- Why are you using `free()`?  You allocated using `new`, not `malloc`.  It looks like you're using `C` learning material instead of `C++` learning material.  You also have this: `struct node *head=NULL` -- there is no need to have `struct` here.  Just plain `node *head = nullptr` is adequate.  Using `struct` here is another sign you're using `C` idioms instead of C++.

Comment: That's before getting into the whole lack of an actual list class. I don't like seeing that C-style linked lists are still taught with C++.

Comment: @273K: Actually, that code is easier to convert to idiomatic C (using malloc instead of new) than idiomatic C++...

Comment: The main mistake here is not using `<forward_list>`. Seriously. Your exercise teaches you nothing, least of all how to effectively use C++...

Comment: In `while(newNode->next!=NULL) { newNode=newNode->next; }` think about what `newNode->next` is after that loop finishes. It's `NULL` (`nullptr`), right? So, setting it `newNode->next=NULL;` ... has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

For starters instead of the C function `free` you shall use the C++ operator `delete`.

Provided that initially the pointer `head` is not equal to `nullptr` then after this while loop the pointer `newNode->next` is equal to `NULL` while the pointer `temp` has either an indeterminate value or is equal to `NULL`.

```
void deleteLast()
{
    newNode=head;
    while(newNode->next!=NULL)
    {
        newNode=newNode->next;
        temp=newNode->next;
    }
    newNode->next=NULL;
    free(temp);

}
```

Also if the deleted node is the node pointed to by `head` then the pointer `head` is not updated.

Using your approach with global variables (it is a bad approach when functions depend on global variables) the function can be defined the following way

```
void deleteLast()
{
    if ( head )
    {
        if ( head->next == nullptr )
        {
            delete head;
            head = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            newNode = head;

            while ( newNode->next->next ) newNode = newNode->next;

            delete newNode->next;
            newNpde->next = nullptr;
        }
    }
}
```

Also within the function `deleteFirst` you shall check whether the pointer `head` is equal to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code:

- Using global variables for local tasks is bad design.  There is no reason for `newNode` or `temp` to be global at all.
- Mixing `new` with `free()` is **undefined behavior**.  You need to `delete` anything you `new`.
- Neither `deleteFirst()` nor `deleteLast()` are accounting for the possibility that the list may be empty (ie, when `head` is `NULL`).
- `main()` is leaking memory.  It is not freeing any of the nodes it creates before exiting.

Now, to answer your question -

The logic in `deleteLast()` is simply wrong. You are `free()`'ing the wrong `node`.  Provided that `head` is not `NULL`, when your loop ends, `newNode` is pointing at the last `node`, and `temp` is `NULL`.  You are not removing the last node at all, you are merely setting the last node's `next` member to `NULL` (which it already is) and then you are calling `free()` with a `NULL` pointer as input, which is a no-op.

You need to set the *2nd-to-last* node's `next` member to `NULL`, and then `delete` the last `node`.  Also, when the list contains only 1 node in it, the last node is the `head` node, but `deleteLast()` is not setting `head` to `NULL` in that scenario.

With that said, try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};
node *head = NULL;

void insertFirst(int data)
{
    node *newNode = new node;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}

void deleteFirst()
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void deleteLast()
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        node *temp = head, *prev = NULL;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if (prev)
            prev->next = NULL;
        else
            head = NULL;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void deleteAll()
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        node *temp = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = temp;
    }
}

void print()
{
    node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    insertFirst(10);
    insertFirst(20);
    insertFirst(30);
    print();

    deleteLast();
    insertFirst(40);
    print();

    deleteAll();
    print();

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/Dzssvg)

Alternatively, `deleteLast()` can be implemented like this instead, eliminating the need for the `prev` variable:

```cpp
void deleteLast()
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        node **temp = &head;

        while ((*temp)->next != NULL) {
            temp = &((*temp)->next);
        }

        delete *temp;
        *temp = NULL;
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/grsngR)

That being said, you really should be using the standard `std::list` container instead of a manual implementation, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

std::list<int> myList;

void print()
{
    for (auto data : myList) {
        std::cout << data << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
     
int main()
{
    myList.push_front(10);
    myList.push_front(20);
    myList.push_front(30);
    print();

    myList.pop_back();
    myList.push_front(40);
    print();

    myList.clear();
    print();

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/7HywJC)